# BibTeX entry for author with only one name

Tags: bibtex

One of several authors on a paper I need to cite has only one name. How do I format the BibTeX entry?

`author = {Smith, J and Jones, S and Singleton and Brown, A}`

Comment: What bibliography style are you using?

Comment: @egreg: I made my own one years ago. If I add the author as `Singleton, {}`, the output is `Singleton, .` which is not what I want. Do I need to run `makebst` again?

Comment: Can you show the entry in the `.bbl` file?

Comment: @egreg: Thanks, but honza's answer below has solved this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What if you use just `author = {Smith, J and Jones, S and {Singleton} and Brown, A}`? That works for me without problems with `natbib`, and a custom style based on `abbrvnat`.